# If someone says "It did not have A as B", do they mean B have A or not?

Tags: meaning

Let's say someone said "This film (from Studio A) didn't have the same magic as other (Studio A) films", do they mean if that movie was all the same like other films with no charm, or that movie was worse than other films with charm?

I want to know if there is a room for interpretation with context, or it is always straightforward.

Comment: Nobody talks about "Studio A" because there is no such place.  Why not write "Marvel Studios" or "Universal". - don't use variables in English.

Comment: @JamesK Using a real studio distracts from the question. Placeholder names have a long history in English. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_name?wprov=sfla1

Comment: Actially I find the use of A and B distracting.  Consider the title ""It did not have A as B", do they mean B have A or not?"  What sort of word do A and B represent?  nouns I suppose, and B seems to represent a plural noun (or perhaps that's a mistake)  Or perhaps this is meant to be a comparative phrase and A represents a phrase with "as".  Perhaps there is a different answer for particular cases of A and B For example perhaps count and non count nouns are treated differently, or perhaps A needs to be an abstract noun.... Using A and B just confounds the matter.

Comment: @JamesK the title is confusing, but not for the reason of placeholdername alone, and it is clarified in the body (which also use placeholder, but better), so it's fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idiom "not have the same [quality A] as B" is straightforward: the thing lacks the [quality A] that B has, and is inferior in that way.

In your terms, the other films have charm and this one doesn't, or at least not to the same standard.

Answer (score 6):

It seems very straightforward.  Other films from Studio A have "magic".  This film doesn't have "magic" (or it has less "magic").

Now there is lots of room for interpretation about what "magic" means here.  It doesn't mean "magic tricks".  It might mean "charm" or it might not.

You can infer that having "magic" is a very good thing for a film, so this film is worse than other films from Studio A, because those other films have magic.  It doesn't compare this film with films from other studios, so it doesn't compare this film with films (with or without "magic") from Studio B, or Studio C.